# Audio output to .wav file is valid, but when encoded with Vorbis, it records silence?

Tags: c++, audio, openal, ogg, vorbis

I've been hunting bugs for the past three days and I've kind of given up.  I've plowed through all the samples in the OpenAL SDK and the Vorbis examples, but to no avail, so I hope someone can help me.

The problem:
I record audio using OpenAL, and for debug reasons i output it to C:/out.wav which i can then play with any audio player of choice and it plays back whatever i recorded.

The exact same buffer i get from openAL is what I input into libvorbisenc
(I request a buffer with vorbis_analysis_buffer and run alcCaptureSamples on it, after which i let vorbis do it's thing.)

**The point being : Why is vorbis returning silence to my output file and how do i get valid compressed audio in my file "C:/out.ogg" ?**

Don't worry about some missing or extra parentheses , they were lost in the copy+paste and removal of comments
the code runs, but it's output just isn't valid.

Relevant defines etc:

```
//due to strange formatting constraints of this site the's are omitted  
define CHANNELS                 1  
define HERTZ                22050  
define BITSPERSAMPLE                16  
define BYTESPERSAMPLE               2  
define SAMPLES              4410  
define  SAMPLESIZE          2  
define ALIGN                (CHANNELS*BITSPERSAMPLE/8)  
define BUFFERSIZE           (SAMPLES*SAMPLESIZE)

typedef struct
{
    char            szRIFF[4];  
    long            lRIFFSize;  
    char            szWave[4];  
    char            szFmt[4];  
    long            lFmtSize;  
    WAVEFORMATEX    wfex;  
    char            szData[4];  
    long            lDataSize;  
} WAVEHEADER;  

class vorbispacker{  
public:  
    vorbispacker();  
    ~vorbispacker();  
    void consume();  

    muxer * mux;  
        // the needed ogg_stream_state is found at this->mux->state;  


    ogg_page         og; /* one Ogg bitstream page.  Vorbis packets are inside */  
    ogg_packet       op; /* one raw packet of data for decode */  

    vorbis_info      vi; /* struct that stores all the static vorbis bitstream  
                         settings */  
    vorbis_comment   vc; /* struct that stores all the user comments */   

    vorbis_dsp_state vd; /* central working state for the packet->PCM decoder */  
    vorbis_block     vb; /* local working space for packet->PCM decode */  
};
```

**vorbis setup**

```
void vorbispacker::setup(){

    this->mux = new muxer;

    vorbis_info_init(&this->vi);
    int ret = vorbis_encode_init_vbr(&this->vi,CHANNELS,HERTZ,0.7);
    vorbis_comment_init(&this->vc);
    vorbis_comment_add_tag(&this->vc,"ENCODER","Test");
    ret =vorbis_analysis_init(&this->vd,&this->vi);
    ret= vorbis_block_init(&this->vd,&this->vb);

    iSize=0;
    iDataSize=0;
    //TEST//

    out = fopen("C:/out.wav","wb");
    // Prepare a WAVE file header for the captured data
    sprintf(swaveheader.szRIFF, "RIFF");
    swaveheader.lRIFFSize = 0;
    sprintf(swaveheader.szWave, "WAVE");
    sprintf(swaveheader.szFmt, "fmt ");
    swaveheader.lFmtSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);        
    swaveheader.wfex.nChannels = CHANNELS;
    swaveheader.wfex.wBitsPerSample = BITSPERSAMPLE;
    swaveheader.wfex.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    swaveheader.wfex.nSamplesPerSec = HERTZ;
    swaveheader.wfex.nBlockAlign = swaveheader.wfex.nChannels * swaveheader.wfex.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    swaveheader.wfex.nAvgBytesPerSec = swaveheader.wfex.nSamplesPerSec * swaveheader.wfex.nBlockAlign;
    swaveheader.wfex.cbSize = 0;
    sprintf(swaveheader.szData, "data");
    swaveheader.lDataSize = 0;

    fwrite(&swaveheader, sizeof(WAVEHEADER), 1, out);




    srand(time(NULL));
    ret = ogg_stream_init(&this->mux->state,rand());


    this->eos=0;

    ogg_packet header;
    ogg_packet header_comm;
    ogg_packet header_code;



    vorbis_analysis_headerout(&this->vd,&this->vc,&header,&header_comm,&header_code);
    ret = ogg_stream_packetin(&this->mux->state,&header); 
    ret =ogg_stream_packetin(&this->mux->state,&header_comm);
    ret =ogg_stream_packetin(&this->mux->state,&header_code);



    while(1){
        int res = ogg_stream_flush(&this->mux->state,&this->og);
        if(!res)break;
        this->mux->write(this->og);

    }


      // this code works great, the headers are correct , and are output to out.ogg


};
```

The problematic code:

```
* // set up buffer*

float ** vorbisbuffer =  vorbis_analysis_buffer(&this->vd,SAMPLES);  
*// retrieve audio samples ( MONO 16 bit)*  
alcCaptureSamples(mic->pdevice,vorbisbuffer[0],SAMPLES);    


    //this goes to debug .wav file -> the exact same buffer that goes into vorbis  
    fwrite(vorbisbuffer[0], BUFFERSIZE, 1, out);  
    iDataSize +=BUFFERSIZE;  

    int eos =0;  




      /* tell the library how much we actually submitted */    

    //SAMPLES is what is inserted into openAL , hence what we put in vorbis  
      vorbis_analysis_wrote(&vd,SAMPLES);    




    while(vorbis_analysis_blockout(&this->vd,&this->vb)==1){

      /* analysis, assume we want to use bitrate management */
      vorbis_analysis(&this->vb,NULL);
      vorbis_bitrate_addblock(&this->vb);

      while(vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket(&this->vd,&this->op)){

        /* weld the packet into the bitstream */
        ogg_stream_packetin(&this->mux->state,&op);

        /* write out pages (if any) */
        while(!eos){
          //if result > 0 there are more packets available
          int result=ogg_stream_pageout(&this->mux->state,&this->og);
          if(result==0)break;
          //write ogg page to stream 
          // since that function outputs the ogg headers OK, i suppose there's no error there.
          this->mux->write(this->og);

          /* this could be set above, but for illustrative purposes, I do
             it here (to show that vorbis does know where the stream ends) */

          if(ogg_page_eos(&og))eos=1;
        }
      }
    }
```

It's a lot to digest, but I really hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting code, if you indent it with four spaces (instead of using `<code>`), it will get properly formatted.  I've edited your post to fix the formatting for you for this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in passing 16 bit samples to a float (32bit!!!) vorbis buffer, where i was assuming float was also 16 bit ( doh)

so allocating a buffer

```
char * data[SAMPLES*2]; // for 16 bit mono samples
```

and moving the stuff over to the float vorbis buffer solves the whole thing

```
vorbisbuffer =  vorbis_analysis_buffer(&this->vd,SAMPLES);//still 4410 samples
alcCaptureSamples(mic->pdevice,data,SAMPLES); // move the data to the  "data"buffer

for(int i =0;i<SAMPLES;i++){
    // make floats out of 16 bit samples
    vorbisbuffer[0][i]=((data[i*2+1]<<8)|(0x00ff&(int)data[i*2]))/32768.f; 
}
```

so for humans thats as follows:

- take the right byte of the sample, shift it 8 bits to the left in a 32 bit buffer
- take the left byte of the sample, and run an AND operator on it with the buffer
- shift the whole thing 16 bits to the left (/32768) (least significant byte first )

might sound over-complicated but when de-interlacing stereo it makes perfect sense, which would look like this ( yes i stole this from the SDK's, but i simply didn't get it when i read it)

```
vorbisbuffer =  vorbis_analysis_buffer(&this->vd,SAMPLES*CHANNELS);
alcCaptureSamples(mic->pdevice,data,SAMPLES); // open al init'ed to stereo16
//where the first dimension is the audio channel and the second the sample index
for(int i =0;i<SAMPLES;i++){  
    vorbisbuffer[0][i]=((data[i*4+1]<<8)|
              (0x00ff&(int)data[i*4]))/32768.f;
    vorbisbuffer[1][i]=((data[i*4+3]<<8)|
              (0x00ff&(int)data[i*4+2]))/32768.f;  
}
```

Comment: may you please provide your input on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193676/ogg-input-stream-time-mismatch/39194020#39194020